# How to pass wildcard via drush exec?

Tags: drush, ssh

How to pass wildcard via drush exec on remote host (via ssh)?

I've tried already:

```
$ drush @foo exec 'ls -al *'
$ drush @foo exec "ls -al *"
sh: 1: ls -al *: not found
Command 'ls -al *' failed.
$ drush @foo exec "ls -al \*"
sh: 1: ls -al \*: not found
Command 'ls -al \*' failed.
$ drush @foo exec 'sh -c "ls -al *"'
```

Local shell is bash, remote shell is sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ drush @foo ssh 'ls -al *'` works great, for any @foo alias that is remote.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing `exec` a string?

```
✔ aw-dgurba ~ > drush help exec
Execute a shell command. Usually used with a site alias.

Examples:
 drush core-execute git pull origin  Retrieve latest code from git 
 rebase

Arguments:
 command                                   The shell command to be executed.

Options:
 --escaped                                 Command string already escaped; do not add additional quoting.                   
 --ssh-options                             A string of extra options that will be passed to the ssh command (e.g. "-p 100") 
 --tty                                     Create a tty (e.g. to run an interactive program).

Aliases: exec, execute
aw-dgurba ~ > drush exec "ls ~/*"
sh: 1: ls ~/*: not found
Command 'ls ~/*' failed.
```

Yet,

```
aw-dgurba ~ > drush exec ls ~/*.txt
/home/dgurba/catch22_excerpt.txt
```

Note the `help description` does not pass a quoted string. If you escaped options already than use `--escaped` option. If you need special handling via ssh then supply the necessary `--ssh-options`.

Comment: Without quotes it doesn't work as well, as wildcard would be interpreted by the local shell. And I'd like to pass wildcard to be interpreted by the remote shell, not local.